# foreach only rendering first cell

Tags: jsf, jstl, panelgrid

This problem has me completely stomped. I am only getting something rendered in the first cell of a panelgrid.

The value of list[0] on the first row will be rendered. If I change the first cell to hold list[1] then that value will be shown. The iterator gives me two rows with empty values. I know for sure that 2 rows are returned with valid values.

It doesn't helt using a h:datatable. Anyone know why this would happen?

Trying this will generate value value

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="#{serviceSeries.getClubAverages(club.name, st, calendarBean)}">
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[0] }" />
                <h:outputText value="value" />
            </c:forEach>

<h:panelGrid columns="8" border="1" cellpadding="3">
            <h:outputText value="Namn" />
            <h:outputText value="Serier" />
            <h:outputText value="Total" />
            <h:outputText value="Snitt" />
            <h:outputText value="Hcp 70% - 200" />
            <h:outputText value="Hcp 80% - 200" />
            <h:outputText value="Hcp 70% - 220" />
            <h:outputText value="Hcp 80% - 220" />

            <c:forEach var="list" items="#{serviceSeries.getClubAverages(club.name, st, calendarBean)}">
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[0] }" />
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[1] }" />
                <h:outputText value="#{list[2] }" />
                <h:outputText value="#{list[3]}"/>
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[4] }" />
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[5] }" />
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[6] }" />
                <h:outputText value="   #{list[7] }" />
            </c:forEach>

            </h:panelGrid>
```

java code :

```
private List CalculateAveragesClub(List results)
    {
                ArrayList alResults = new ArrayList();

    //Calculates some stuff and return two rows with 8 columns in
        alResults.add(playerInfo);
        System.out.println(playerInfo[0]);
        return alResults;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML output?

Comment: Yes there is only the first cells information. All others are <td></td>

Comment: Well, apparently model is broken and `<c:forEach>` is merely the presenter here.

Comment: what do you mean by model?

Comment: Uh, it's that whatever `#{serviceSeries.getClubAverages(...)}` returns.

Comment: I know for sure that it will return two rows with 8 columns and exactly containing the names and averages of the persons I expect.

Comment: That can be, but the symptoms suggest otherwise :)

Comment: could be but doing list[2], list[3] etc. in the first cell will render all results of the first row. So I am pretty sure that all the info is there it's just not rendered.

Comment: Switching to windows. Getting the project again from git solved the rendering problem. Strange that eclipse on linux will not give me the same result